# How to stop HttpClient.GetAsync(uri) from hanging?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I have the following code that I'm using to call a uri:

```
var uri = string.Format("Helpers/ProfileList/Online/?locationId=0&skip=0&take={0}", numProfiles);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

The uri is pointing at a custom web api uri (which I can debug and follow through). However, when the last return statement in the api has been called, nothing seems to happen. It should go to the `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();` line, but it's not. It just seems to be hanging.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My spidey-sense tells me that further up your call stack your code is blocking on a returned task, e.g., `Task.Wait` or `Task<T>.Result`. By default, this will [cause a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that I explain on my blog.

To fix it, replace `Task.Wait` and `Task<T>.Result` with `await`.

Comment: I was just going to suggest trying `await client.GetAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false)`, which might eliminate a deadlock like that :)

Comment: Yeah I found that fix just after writing the question (in the "related" column on the right hand side)

Comment: `ConfigureAwait` is more of a workaround than a solution, IMO; you end up with more brittle code. The more proper solution is to use `await` instead of `Wait` or `Result`.