# client.GetAsync call hangs when calling the api from wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, http

I have a problem when calling the api application I'm running in a different project. When I debug, I can see the call hits the right controller in the api. After I click continue, it just hangs and nothing happens.

**Method where I make the call to the Api**

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<Room>> SearchForAvailableRooms(DateTime from, DateTime to, bool smoke, bool minibar, int rooms, int customers)
{
    ObservableCollection<Room> data = new ObservableCollection<Room>();

    // Call api to get rooms
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:15998/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    // New code:
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/room");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var jsonAsString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Response message is not OK. Issues in action: {0}", "api/room"));
    }

    return null;
}
```

The client.GetAsync("api/room") makes the call to the api, but after it dosen't get any further.. The if or else are not being hitted.

Have read that the method call will causing a deadlock (hanging) from this stack post:[Link to the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987895/how-to-stop-httpclient-getasyncuri-from-hanging)

He explain it has something to do where I make the call to the method.
Right now I'm using these lines to call the method:

```
var task = _getRoomsService.SearchForAvailableRooms(searchModel.From, searchModel.To, searchModel.Smoke, searchModel.Minibar, searchModel.RoomValue, searchModel.CustomerValue);
var result = task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
RoomsList = result;
```

Can any see what could be wrong here?

**Update:**

What I also have tried:

```
RoomsList = await _getRoomsService.SearchForAvailableRooms(searchModel.From, searchModel.To, searchModel.Smoke, searchModel.Minibar, searchModel.RoomValue, searchModel.CustomerValue);
```

This gives me an error --> Await operator can only be used within async method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely call this on UI thread. When your method calls into `client.GetAsync`, context is remembered so that part after async call might execute on the same context as the part before. This is done for your convenience - after returning from `client.GetAsync` you are back on UI thread and can safely work with user interface controls.

But in this case you are blocking user interface thread by calling:

```
task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

So UI thread is blocked by this and after `client.GetAsync` has finished - it cannot return back to UI thread - hence you are deadlocked. That's if explain in simple terms.

To fix, just don't block UI thread (you don't need anyway):

```
RoomsList = await _getRoomsService.SearchForAvailableRooms(searchModel.From, searchModel.To, searchModel.Smoke, searchModel.Minibar, searchModel.RoomValue, searchModel.CustomerValue);
```

Comment: Have tried this, it tells me that await operator can only be used within async method, but funny thing that my method is an async method?

Comment: You need to mark method where you do this as async. Suppose you are doing this in button click handler, then just do "async void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)"

Comment: Okay, I give it a try! hang on!

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply ;) now I finally got a respond from the api! you rockz!